# Does ngStorage support any means to broadcast post-change events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

The [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) module [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) supports automatic binding to local storage, but is there any way to find out after a snyc has completed?

I need to perform a post-sync action, so a change event would be ideal.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the sync is happening, I would just place a watch on the scope variable object that you are updating.